# Prove these two segments are equal

Tags: geometry

$AB$ and $AC$ are tangents to the circle.

$BP||AC$

$MBA=APB$

$BFP=BAC$

$Prove AM=MC$
[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: By the way, next time try to add as much information on what you tried as possible. If you don't you get downvotes from people.

Comment: **Hint:** AB $\cong$ AC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $PB$ is parallel to $AC$, $\, \,\angle BPF = \angle MAF =  \alpha$. On the other hand, due to the fact the $BA$ is tangent to the circle at point $B$,  $\,\, \angle MBA = \angle FBA = \angle BPF = \alpha$. Hence $\angle MBA = \angle MAF = \alpha$ and so triangles $MAF$ and $MBA$ are similar (one common angle at vertex $M$ and $\angle MBA = \angle MAF = \alpha$). Therefore $\frac{MF}{MA}=\frac{MA}{MB}$ which is equivalent to $MA^2 = MF \cdot MB$. On the other hand, $MC$ is tangent to the circle at point $C$ giving us the equality $MC^2 = MF \cdot MB$. Consequently $MC^2 = MF \cdot MB = MA^2$, which means that $MC = MA$.

Comment: $PB$ is parallel to $AC$ so $\angle BPF$ and $\angle MCF$ are obtained by intersecting two parallel lines, $PB$ and $AC$, with a common line, $PC$. That's why the two angles are equal. This is one interpretation of Euclid's original axiom of parallel lines, isn't it?

Comment: It is not correct, $∠BPF$ can not be equal to $∠MCF$.

Comment: My notations are not the same as yours. That's why the confusion.

Comment: Fixed. Everything matches now.