# Similar Triangles and the Power of a Point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let a line $k$ be tangent to a circle $o$ at a point $D$.  Let $A$ and $B$ be points on $o$ such that $AB$ is parallel to $k$.  Let $C$ be a point on $k$ such that the line segments $CA, CB$ intersect $o$ in points $E$ and $F$.  Prove that the line $EF$ intersects $CD$ in a point $M$ that is the centre of $CD$.  Hint:  prove that $\angle ECD=\angle MFC$ and find similar triangles to compute $|M C|$.  Then use the power of $M$ with respect to $o$ to compute $|M D|$

I tried using the hint but I could not prove the angle part. I tried using Thales with respect to the point $F$ and the segment $MC$ and line $AB$ but I did not get anything,

Any help would be appreciated,

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove these two segments are equal](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898472/prove-these-two-segments-are-equal)

Answer (score 0):

$ABFE$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, then (by property of cyclic quadrilateral)
$$\angle EAB =\angle EFC$$
Also $\angle EAB =\angle MCE$, because $AB$ is parallel to $DC$.
From this we have that $MCE \sim MFC$. Hence
$$\frac{MC}{MF}=\frac{ME}{MC}$$
This implies that $ME\cdot MF=MC^2$.
From here is easy conclude the problem.